# Testing method with parameter marked with @Context annotation

Tags: java, spring, testing, junit

i have a function that receives parameter HttpHeaders marked with @Context jakarta annotation.

It looks like this :

```
public Response login(
            @HeaderParam(H_FIRM) String firm,
            @QueryParam("rememberme") Boolean rememberme,
            @Context HttpHeaders headers,
            @Context UriInfo uriInfo
    ) { }
```

And my question is how can i provide HttpHeaders to test which looks more or less like this:

```
@Test
    @OperateOnDeployment(IT)
    public void loginWithoutValidityTest() {
        //when
        Response response = authResource.login('parameters')
        //then
        assertEquals(200, response.getStatus());
    }
```

Thanks in advance for any answers, ive been struggling with this for a long time.

Comment: Don't test that method by calling it directly. Use a REST endpoint testing framework.

Comment: I have done it with REST framework which was quite easy, but now i have to do this like this and this is the problem. @Jorn

Comment: Right, so you know how to do it properly, but you're choosing not to. I can't help you with that other than to say: Don't.